# kendo grid resizing when a column is removed

Tags: resize, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in my application.

[image]

There are situations when I need to remove the Resource Naam column and then I get this.

[image]

But I want the grid to take the whole of the screen. How can I solve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Without fixed width in the columns, it will resize properly.